# Proper VARIANT initialization

Tags: c++, com, mfc, automation, variant

I'm dealing with a project that has some of the COM/Automation stuff written in C++. I know that MFC/ATL has a nifty [CComVariant class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac97df2h.aspx) that takes care of the VARIANT initialization, but just from the standpoint of "pure" VARIANT, I know that the following is recommended way to init it:

```
VARIANT v;
::VariantInit(&v);
```

but I'm wondering from reading the description to [VariantInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), can I just do this instead?

```
VARIANT v = {0};
```

Comment: Or `struct Variant : VARIANT { Variant() { VariantInit(this); } };`

Comment: Yes, `VARIANT v = {0};` works. Or `VARIANT v = {VT_EMPTY};` to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, `VariantInit` simply set the `vt` member to `VT_EMPTY`.  It does not zero out the contents of the union because `VT_EMPTY` is interpreted as having no data.  You can use any other method to set `vt` to `VT_EMPTY` and it's fine, but the *standard* and *correct* way is to use `VariantInit`.